# ASP.NET Page ViewData Overwritten (missing)

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

Contents of _ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    ViewData["IndexLink"] = Context.Request.Path != "/" ? "/Index" : "";
}
```

Contents of Downloads.cshtml

```
@page
@model DownloadsModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Downloads";
}
```

Snippet from _Layout.cshtml

```
<title>@ViewData["Title"] - ABC Sofware LLC</title>
```

**Problem:**

The `<title>` tag is being rendered without the view's title.

**Troubleshooting Steps:**

I put a break point in `_Layout.cshtml` to see what
ViewData contains. It has one key instead of two.

```
@ViewData.Keys
    Count = 1
    [0]: "IndexLink"
```

If I remove the `ViewData["IndexLink"]` line from _ViewStart.cshtml then `ViewData["Title"]` is set.

```
@ViewData.Keys
    Count = 1
    [0]: "Title"
```

Why does setting a `ViewData` key in `_ViewStart.html` break `ViewData` in the views?

Comment: I tried the same scenario, it seems to be working fine. How did you created an project?

Comment: @AntonySamyJoseph VS2017 > New ASP.NET Core Web Application > Web Application. I just tried it with a brand new test project and the issue is the same.

Comment: I also tried same configuration.. but asp.net core 2.0..

Comment: I also was using version 2.0

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  It seems that in Core 2.x, ViewData is overwritten if any key is set in _Layout.cshtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is currently a bug (see https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7675 -- planned to be fixed in Core 2.2.0) but the current workaround is instead of:

```
ViewData["Key"]
```

you would use

```
ViewContext.ViewData["Key"]
```

in both _ViewStart.cshtml and Downloads.cshtml.  Referencing

```
@ViewData["Key"]
```

in _Layout.cshtml still seems to work fine for me.